# increase points and reset points game script in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am writing a 2D game in unity. I  created a function for increasing points and resetting points to zero.

The problem is that whenever I am losing the game and hitting "play again," the `points` and `ballSpeed` start from the same values from where I lost. I want them to reset.

Here's my code:

shooterMain.cs

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public static class shooterMain {
public enum ShooterStatenum{shielded,Vulnerable};

private static float ballSpeed = 2;
private static int points = 0;
private static int lives = 0;
public static ShooterStatenum shooterState = ShooterStatenum.Vulnerable;

public static float getBallSpeed ()
{
    return ballSpeed;
}

public static void IncreaseSpeed()
{
    ballSpeed += 0.2f;
}

public static void increasePoint()
{
    points++;
}

public static void ResetSpeed()
{
    return ballSpeed;
}

public static void ResetPoint()
{
    return points;
}

public static int getPoints()
{
    return points;
}

public static int getLives(){

    return lives;

}

public static void addLives(){

    lives++;

}
```

coinhandler.cs

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class coinhandler : MonoBehaviour {

public Transform particles;
// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}

void OnCollisionEnter2D (Collision2D collider)
{
    if (collider.gameObject.tag == "Player") 
    {
        Instantiate (particles, new Vector3 (transform.position.x, transform.position.y, -0.2f), Quaternion.identity);
        shooterMain.getBallSpeed ();
        shooterMain.getPoints ();
        GameObject.FindWithTag ("points").GetComponent<Text>().text = shooterMain.getPoints ().ToString ();  
        Destroy (gameObject);
    }
}
```

bombHandler.cs

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class bombHandler : MonoBehaviour {

public Transform particles;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    Destroy (gameObject, 6f);
}

void OnCollisionEnter2D (Collision2D collider)
{
    if (collider.gameObject.tag == "Player") 
    {
        Instantiate (particles, new Vector3 (transform.position.x, transform.position.y, -0.2f), Quaternion.identity);
        Destroy (gameObject);
        if (shooterMain.getLives () == 0 && shooterMain.shooterState == shooterMain.ShooterStatenum.Vulnerable) 
        {
            //shooterMain.getLives (0);
            shooterMain.ResetSpeed ();
            shooterMain.ResetPoint ();
            GameObject.FindWithTag ("points").GetComponent<Text>().text = shooterMain.getPoints ().ToString ();
            SceneManager.LoadScene (0);
        }
    }
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}
}
```

Comment: They are all marked as `static`. Simply, add another function that resets all those `static` variables to their default value then call that method when needed.

Comment: @Programmer and you please answer it editing my script?

Comment: @Programmer i really didn't get it... can show me editing my script?

Comment: Not sure what's hard about my comment. The reset functions should **reset** the variables. For example, `ballSpeed = 2`....`points = 0` and `lives = 0`. That's it. This is what you should be doing in the `ResetSpeed` and `ResetPoint` functions instead of returning the variables in a `void` function...Does that even compile? By the way, you should also make the `shooterMain` class  singleton. I don't have time to answer this question at this moment but anyone who feels like should.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As 'Programmer' already commented (sorry, don't have enough reputation to comment), you have to actually reset your static variables in the respective methods. You returned the variables instead - and I don't know what editor / compiler you are using, but any Visual Studio version since ... ever ... will not compile that.

Anyways, replace your code with this:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public static class shooterMain {
public enum ShooterStatenum{shielded,Vulnerable};

private static float ballSpeed = 2;
private static int points = 0;
private static int lives = 0;
public static ShooterStatenum shooterState = ShooterStatenum.Vulnerable;

public static float getBallSpeed ()
{
    return ballSpeed;
}

public static void IncreaseSpeed()
{
    ballSpeed += 0.2f;
}

public static void increasePoint()
{
    points++;
}

public static void ResetSpeed()
{
    ballSpeed = 2;
}

public static void ResetPoint()
{
    points = 0;
}

public static int getPoints()
{
    return points;
}

public static int getLives(){

    return lives;

}

public static void addLives(){

    lives++;

}
```

And yes, 'Programmer' is right about making that class singleton, but i think thats a bit too much for a learner, so just ignore that for now.

Comment: okay, thanks it worked but... i also had to make some changes in coinhandler.cs as "shooterMain.getBallSpeed (); & shooterMain.getPoints ();" to "shooterMain.IncreaseSpeed (); & shooterMain.increasePoint ();"... and it is working right now... it won't give me any problem right?

Comment: Since I didn't change any of those methods in shooterMain, there souldn't be any problems resulting in using the code stated above.

Comment: @SumitPal Calling a function that starts with "Get" without using the return value, when the sole purpose is returning a variable, was never a good idea in the first place. So if you actually want to increase the speed and points when you get a coin, then calling increaseSpeed/Point like you said is the right way.

Answer (score 3):

As Programmer mentioned in the comments, you should simply add a method that resets every variable that you want to be reset to their default values.

There's no big complication here, the hardest part is probably finding all the variables that you want to reset.

```
public static void Reset ()
{
    ballSpeed = 0;
    lives = 2;
    points = 0;
}
```

---

Another thing to mention is that your code probably doesn't even compile, because of your `ResetPoints` and `ResetSpeed` methods, which are return `void`, meaning that they return *nothing*. You can't do `return lives;` as that would tell the method to return in integer, not a void.

You are probably being confused with what `return` does. `return` exits the method currently being executed, together with passing a value back to where the method was called. If the method is of type `int` this value will be an integer, if it is of type `void` it won't return a value at all.

---

If you understood all this and feel confident about improving your code further, you should implement your `shooterMain` class as a [singleton](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/Singleton). This will ensure that there will always only be one instance of it, which is useful when working with variables that should only exist once.

Comment: Thank You! I got it will see about singleton... for now i have got my problem solved... Thanks again for all the support. :)

Answer (score 1):

GameObject.FindWithTag ("points").GetComponent().text = "0"

in  Start() of coinhandler.cs .. that would be the simplest solution! for the very first time when coin handler will get rendered it will make the score zero and you are already updating it in using onCollision in the perFrame working method.. a job nice done for a starter.. happy hunting

Comment: That would just set the text to 0 and only when he exits out of playmode and starts the game again. Thats not what he needs.

Comment: Thank you for the simplest answer but it's not the solution i was looking for... because if i want to reset some other values  it won't work right? anyways i have got it solve... thank you.